# Withing last 7 days

Tags: php

Just can't get this to work. I want to check if this user bought a $45 or more bid pack in the last 7 days.

```
    $big_amount="45";
    //check if the user has purchased bids
    $strFind="SELECT * FROM `prepaypal` WHERE `memid`=\"$curmemid\" AND `success`='Y' 
    AND `pid`='0' AND `amount`>=\"$big_amount\" BETWEEN NOW() and DATE_SUB
    (`date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1";
    //echo $strFind;
    $result=mysql_query($strFind) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $bought_bids=$row['id'];
```

Comment: you mean, your query does not work? or you can't fetch data? what does not work?

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: Also use single quotes for your values, that is `\`memid\`='$curmemid'` instead of `\`memid\`=\"$curmemid\"`.

Comment: it returns a wrong result. no where close

Comment: We are not a debugging service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That select statement is not right at all, you should do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `prepaypal` WHERE `memid`= $curmemid AND `success`='Y' AND `pid`='0' AND `amount`>=$big_amount where date >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day order by date DESC;
```

`SYSDATE()` returns the time at which the function executes and interval sets a time period between the given dates.
It's also better to optimize your queries and to get specific values off the database than to do `"SELECT *"`
For example: `SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 from table;`

MySQL_ PHP functions are deprecated as well, so you shouldn't use them anymore. I would stick to Mysqli or PDO prepared statements.

If this doesn't qualify as a correct answer to you, feel free to downvote.